# How to not automatically include an inserted excel column in an adjacent table using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I hope this is an easy question and solution, but I couldn't find anything on how to "temporarily" turn off the "including new rows and columns in table" I know that in the Excel options in Proofing there's a checkbox just for this, but can this be controlled within a VBA macro?

I'm a newbie so please be nice :)

Thanks!

Comment: transform table to range, do the stuff, - later transform it back to table

Comment: Insert into column after that, then delete skipped column.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA the syntax is

```
 Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False
```

and you would replicate that line, with *True* instead, when you wanted to re-enable it.